# Why a useHook runs when initial state is set?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a piece of data managed by `useState()`:

```
const [data, setData] = useState() // undefined as the initial state

useEffect(() => {
  loadandSetData(setData) // some fetch then running setData to change data object
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Will request additional data...')
  console.log(data)
  loadSomeOtherData() // Should be executed only when data turns from undefined to something
}, [data]);
```

The idea is to load some basic information from an endpoint, then load some other data from another endpoint, then combine them together for further consumption.

I want to run the first request on start and run the next one only when data is not `undefined`.
In fact, I see `console.log` running twice - first time with `undefined` value, the second time with something loaded with the first `useEffect` call.

Is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong, and how do I make sure that `loadSomeOtherData()` runs when there is something in `data` object besides checking it explicitly inside the `loadSomeOtherData(data)` call?

Comment: `loadandSetData().then(() => loadSomeOtherData())`?

Comment: Yes, this is an expected behavior in React. [The docs say the following](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (the emphasis is mine):
_When React renders our component, it will remember the effect we used, and then run our effect after updating the DOM. **This happens for every render, including the first one.**_

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavior. Even though your dependency array in your second hook has `data` inside, it is always executed once mounted.

Now, you don't need to use two `useEffect`s in order to have your desired behavior. You can have an async function inside your `useEffect` and wait for the first data to finish and continue with the second one using `async...await` or `Promise.then()` (whichever you prefer)

Something like:

```
const [data, setData] = useState() // undefined as the initial state
useEffect(async () => {
  const someData = await loadandSetData() // this returns a promise that resolves with the data retrieved (i.e a fetch()) - change name of variable
  // here you already have someData
  const someOtherData = await loadSomeOtherData(); // same as above
  // here you already have someOtherData
  
  setData([...someData, ...someOtherData]); // supposing both are array objects and you want to concat them using the spread operator
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour, useEffect does run after each render, including the initial render. You should however change how you use useEffect, to get the behaviour you want.

```
useEffect(() => {
  
    if (data !== undefined) {
        // now the following will only execute when data is not undefined
        console.log('Will request additional data...')
        console.log(data)
        loadSomeOtherData()
    }
}, [data])
```

another option is to call the loadSomeOtherData in the same effect with loadAndSetData

```
useEffect(() => {
  // seems from the signature of how you used loadAndSetData that it takes a callback with a data object, so you could do this
  loadandSetData(data => {
      setData(data)
      loadSomeOtherData()
  }) 
}, []);
```